# Make AdjacencyGraph hide single unconnected elements

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there a way to force `AdjacencyGraph` to hide single unconnected or self connected elements?

```
AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1,
    1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to remove them, there's probably a way to hide them through VertexShape and EdgeShape, but this is likely going to be more difficult and the way the graph is drawn will still be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to hide them, I recommend removing them.

```
comps = Flatten@DeleteCases[WeaklyConnectedComponents[g], {_}]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

Subgraph[g, comps]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to find unconnected vertices  using `VertexComponent` and `VertexDelete` them:

```
VertexDelete[g, _?(VertexComponent[UndirectedGraph@g, #] === {#} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: It should have been `WeaklyConnectedComponents`. I fixed it now, thanks for spotting the mistake!